# Black Line appears after adding second form to a VB .NET page?

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, page-break

I have a page created from a master page. the master page has a form tag which contains the contents on the body tag and then i have a form on the page created from the master to handle uploading a file:

Master:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
page content here
<asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:contentplaceholder>
</form>
```

Page:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="File1" name="File1" runat="server" />
<input type="submit" id="Submit1" value="Upload" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="UploadErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="fileOne" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

in my css file i've added rules to eliminate any borders:

```
form {
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Heres a picture (please note that this black line goes away if i comment out the upload form) :
http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/7503/blackline.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the problem isn't evident from the code you posted above. I would really recommend using a tool such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) which will allow you to quickly identify and isolate the html and css causing the black bar.

Once you install firebug, just hover over the black bar, right-click and select `Inspect Element`.

Form tags can also not be nested. You will need to remove the form tag on the child page for the form to function properly.

Comment: Tyvm Chris i will try what you have recommened

Comment: yep, error doesn't occur with opera/firefox/visual studios internal browser. Only IE has this problem